# Sound device in Ubuntu through VMWare (Windows 7 host)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, vmware, linux-device-driver

I am using VMWare on Windows 7 to run Ubuntu 10.10.

I'm trying to interact with the sound device through Ubuntu, but there is no /dev/dsp or /dev/audio or similar. I do hear sound coming from the system so somehow VMWare is piping it through, but I do not know what device to use to generate my own from my program, or how to get the system to create one that I can use.  Has anyone dealt with this issue before?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this problem is due to pulseaudio being used in the latest versions of Ubuntu.  The solution that worked for me is to use padsp to run my executable which tricks it into thinking there's a /dev/dsp device for it to use, while it's actually redirecting sound to itself.

The issue had nothing to do with VMWare, but with an update in Ubuntu!

http://linux.die.net/man/1/padsp

Answer (score 0):

May be that VMWare is presenting a soundcard supported by ALSA, in which case it is at /dev/snd/

I've never tried developing sound software in VMWare... TBH I think its sound support is a little squirrelly.  I like VirtualBox's sound support better, even if it does have 1/10th second or so latency.  I found VMWare's sound tended to crackle and occasionally play at the wrong speed on my HP DV7 laptop when running Vector as a browsing appliance.